# Windows Forms: SelectionChanged event for TextBox class

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

How do I get notified of a selection change in a text box in .NET 2.0? I was unable to find a SelectionChanged event or an OnSelectionChanged method. What is the best workaround for this (without having to PInvoke, of course)?

Comment: What do you mean "Selection Changed"? Do you mean when a user moves the cursor from one text box to another?

Comment: I think he means a selection of the Text inside the Box.

Comment: I mean that the user has changed what is selected within the text box. Supposing the text box contains "quick brown fox" with "brown" selected and the user then selects "fox" instead, I need to be notified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a RichTextBox and set Multiline to false. It has a OnSelectionChanged.

Comment: A great idea. Any disadvantages?

Comment: I don't know from the top of my head. Might be you need a little tweaking to get it as dumb as a TextBox ;)

Comment: @Vulcan Eager: RichTextBox does have the annoying feature of changing all `\r\n` line endings in the `Text` property to `\n` as soon as it becomes visible.

Answer (score 5):

You can use TextBox also.

Write a function GetMyPosition() and put in the events

- TextChanged()
- MouseClick()
- KeyUp() (In KeyDown() the position isn't changed)

When you want to notify the highlighting of a text, you also have to use

- MouseHover()

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/726ed524-b657-46bc-b5c1-5b8ae1d9fffe/#)  may help! You will need to use RichTextBox still.

Answer (score -1):

“selection change in a text box” If this means SelectedText changed than I needed to do this with a combo box.
How:
Created a MouseUp event which requires if selected text length > 0

Comment: The selection may also change due to keyboard input or through Cut or Undo.