# Cursor position changed event

Tags: c#, silverlight, richtextbox

I'm trying to extract the font of the next character after the current position of the cursor from a `RichTextBox`. This needs to be done everytime the cursor is moved in the `RichTextBox`. I haven't found the event for when the cursor position changes.

Does this event even exist? If not, is there another way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647963/windows-forms-selectionchanged-event-for-textbox-class

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate question... To know it's a duplicate question (when asking the question) he'd have to know that changes in the cursor position have something to do with the selection change event. If he knew that, he'd either be asking a different question, or he wouldn't be asking the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried [RichTextBox.SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.selectionchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Event?

Comment: That is the Silverlight specific link, with little details. This is the 4.5 .Net link with much more detail (assuming the question isn't Sivlerlight): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Also, we generally don't support link only answers, as links can change over time.