# Create event for WinForm usercontrol property changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, textbox

I want to raise an event whenever the SelectedText or `SelectionStart` properties of a TextBox control are changed. Is there any simple way to do so that doesn't involve writing a custom TextBox control from scratch?

Obviously, one option would be having a timer check those properties for changes, but I would prefer not using any timers.

So far I have tried creating a control that inherits from TextBox and overrides the SelectedText property, but that failed. Plus, `SelectionStart` can't be overridden.

Yes, I am aware that the RichTextBox control has the `SelectionChanged` event. I need a normal TextBox, however, not a RichTextBox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647963/windows-forms-selectionchanged-event-for-textbox-class

There is this.. from what I've seen its the only way possible to do this

Comment: Yeah, I read that, my main issue with the RichTextBox control is the lack of precise selection control; it likes to always automatically highlight the entire word for me, even with the AutoWordSelection property set to false. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678620/c-sharp-richtextbox-selection-problem has a solution to that but I would still prefer to use an ordinary TextBox.

Comment: Your only other option then is dependant on why you need to use it.. you could look at DataBinding and bind the selectionlength property to a control?

Comment: I was looking for a more KISS-style solution, to be honest. So there really isn't a way to implement a SelectionChanged event equivalent in the TextBox control?

Comment: Not that I know of sorry, I don't think textboxes are smart enough to do anything with their selection other than using its selection start and length

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve your goal from the `TextBox`, but below is sample of solution that uses inheritance and custom component. `SelectionChanged` event will be raised after user selects some new text by the mouse.

Note, that `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events along with `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties are public in `TextBox`, so you can avoid subclassing if you need.

```
class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

    private int _selectionStart;
    private int _selectionLength;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _selectionStart = SelectionStart;
        _selectionLength = SelectionLength;

        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != SelectionChanged && (_selectionStart != SelectionStart || _selectionLength != SelectionLength))
            SelectionChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
}
```