# SelectionChanged Event For Regular TextBox?

Tags: vb.net

I've been doing some research and I can't seem to find any type of event for SelectionChanged for a **regular** *textbox*. Can anyone please help me with this. I ***do not*** want to use a RichTextBox. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Forms or WPF ?

Comment: I'm using Forms in Visual Studio

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Your answer isn't in VB. You gave me an answer in a different language than I'm looking for...

Comment: Sorry, going to craft you a VB version :/

Comment: It's alright, it happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Forms: SelectionChanged event for TextBox class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647963/windows-forms-selectionchanged-event-for-textbox-class)

Answer (score 0):

By listening to the [MouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the `TextBox`, you can *roughly* get a similar behavior :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler TextBox1.MouseUp, AddressOf TextBox1_OnMouseUp
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_OnMouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        Dim selectedText As String = textBox.SelectedText
        Console.WriteLine(selectedText)
    End Sub


End Class
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Edit:**

Additionally, to properly react during double-clicks, you can encompass your code with the following safe-guard, it will ensure to not output false positives during the first click.

```
Dim isNullOrEmpty As Boolean = String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedText)
If Not isNullOrEmpty Then
    Console.WriteLine(selectedText) // your code
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the link below:

[**TextBox.SelectionChanged Event - MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionchanged(v=vs.95).aspx)

Occurs when the text selection has changed.

```
'Declaration
Public Event SelectionChanged As RoutedEventHandler
```

Comment: That link is for Silverlight.  While the asker didn't specify initially, a comment indicates this question is about WinForms.